# Rendering a circle before unordered list text using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-material-design

Trying to put a Material Design CSS font in front of my text using the following jQuery:

```
    // Build the unordered list of classes with their name and CRN
    var text = '';
    text += '<ul class="list-group class-cart">';
    for (i = 0; i < result.classes[index].length; i++) {
        text += '<li class="list-group-item mdi-image-lens">' + result.classes[index][i]['short_name'] + ' (' + result.classes[index][i]['crn'] + ')</li>';
    }
    text += '</ul>';
```

I am using this library: http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html

In particular, the `mdi-image-lens` icon.

I am trying to emulate this effect from Sunrise Calendar:

[image]

Doing that, this is what I received:

[image]

Oh God, it's hideous.

This is what it normally looks like:

[image]

Any ideas how I can preserve the text size and properties, but also render a nice looking circle (not bullet point, since it's too small to achieve the desired effect) right before the text? Secondly, I also have a variable called:

`result.classes[index][i]['color']` which has a hex color value. I would like to use this hex value as the color of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Material Design icon sets added weird stylings to the text afterwards, so I ended up using a custom glyphicon like the following and put it in a `span` with an in-line style.

```
 * Circle glyphicon */
.glyphicon.glyphicon-dot:before {
  content: "\25cf";
  font-size: 1.7em;
}
```

Trust me, I feel terrible about using an in-line style, but I couldn't think of any other way to assign color to the `glyphicon-dot` class on since each event has its own color attribute.

Answer (score 1):

● ← How about using a unicode circle?

It's a bit bigger than the bullet point (•).

HTML entity for the unicode circle is `&#9679;`.

Comment: Not bad. How would I apply a color JUST to this?

Comment: I would wrap it in a span, and style the span, like this: **HTML:** `<span class="bullet">&#8592;</span>` **CSS:** `.bullet {color: red}`.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Hah, looks gorgeous! Glad I could help, and glad you got it working!

Comment: @DavidThomas Very much appreciated, though remember theGreenCabbage still has 2 more minutes to go until he is allowed to do that! (15min no-acceptance period after a question is asked).

Comment: @DavidThomas Same reason Maximillian said. I couldn't accept it yet.

Comment: One minor question. If you look at this clearly, the bottom is slightly cut off: http://puu.sh/jJZDo/7882ae7f04.png I looked at the `Computed` and toggled a few items on and off, but couldn't get rid of that cut off. I even put in a `margin-bottom`.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Try reducing the font size for the span a little bit.

Comment: It looks like the unicode letter doesn't work on Windows 7 Chrome :/

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Then it looks like it's [time for plan B!](https://jsfiddle.net/81ndup4h/1/)